# Injecting a dependency that is a tree of dependencies

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, anti-patterns

Is it a pattern or antipattern to inject a dependency that is a tree of dependencies?

For example:

```
public class ClassExample
{
    private IContainer _container;

    public ClassExample(IContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }
}

public interface IContainer
{
    IDependencyA DependencyA { get; set; }
    IDependencyB DependencyB { get; set; }
    IDependencyC DependencyC { get; set; }
}

public interface IDependencyA
{
}

public interface IDependencyB
{
}

public interface IDependencyC
{
}
```

The above example could be made even deeper (a tree) - for example IDependencyA could contain even more dependencies IDependencyAA, IDependencyAB, etc.

Someone might use above method to minimize code duplication when having multiple places where a same set of services need to be injected. Code will end up looking like: `container.DependencyA.DependencyAA.Method(...)` in many cases which makes it more verbose and less DRY.

Is using above method a good or bad idea (pattern/antipattern)? Or when is it a good idea, and when is it a bad one?

Comment: _"having multiple places where a same set of services need to be injected"_ - sounds like you could use an abstract base class. _"Code will end up looking like: `container.DependencyA.DependencyAA.Method(...)`"_ - looks like you're not hiding your implementation well enough. If you want `DependencyA` to do something, why would you need to know that it in turn has a `DependencyAA` containing the actual `Method()` you want to call? Show some realistic examples and consider you need major refactoring.

Comment: To me, this would only be acceptable if all three dependencies are in fact required everywhere IContainer is used.

Comment: It is a good idea if you want to hide the number of dependencies that a class relies on.

Comment: The Dependency Injection works well when the number of dependencies is reasonable however it tends to lead to something called *Dependency Over-Injection* which is an anti-pattern. To solve that problem we could use *Factory* but before that we should consider that we might have already broken the Single Responsibility principle and that this class could be split to few classes.

Comment: Using a factory to reduce your number of dependencies often doesn't help. You are either injecting the factory (in which case the number of injected dependencies remains the same), or effectively using Service Locator - which doesn't reduce the number of dependencies, it just _hides_ them.

Comment: The main problem with your `IContainer` abstraction is that it is not hiding complexity from `ClassExample`. Although it might remove the constructor over-injection code smell, it doesn't fix the underlying problem of _why_ constructor over-injection is happening in the first place. Most likely, a class with too many dependencies is too complex; it violates the Single Responsibility Principle. Wrapping dependencies with an `IContainer` abstraction does not change that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think its a particularly *good* pattern*, but by the same token, it's not going to make a huge amount of difference.

If, using your example, `ClassExample` depends on `IDependencyA`, `IDependencyB` & `IDependencyC` then they should all be injected in as dependencies.

It's more usual that the concrete implementations of your `IDependencyXX` classes themselves have dependencies, but do not expose them to `ClassExample` as your description implies.

---

* It's a bad decision primarily because, sooner or later, people will start injecting `IContainer` when they only need `IDependencyA` and `IDependencyB` (but not `IDependencyC`). And this is redundant. The whole point of Injection is to inject the dependencies you need, not every possible dependency from the system "just in case"

Comment: Could you give an explanation as to why you said: `I don't think its a particularly good pattern` ? Without an explanation it would be just taking your word for it.

Comment: So you are basically saying that you have an opinion that is not based on evidence, but on intuition or something like that?

Comment: Pretty much - 20 years of it ;)

Comment: @RăzvanFlaviusPanda I have added one obvious problem that comes to mind (yes, based on experience & intuition)

Comment: @RăzvanFlaviusPanda Let's say `ClassA` takes a dependency on `IContainer`. Now `ClassB` -> `ClassH` also take a dependency on `IContainer`. Now `ClassH` needs an extra dependency. What do you do? You shouldn't add it to `IContainer` (since the other 7 users don't need it). So you'd better have `ClassH` depend on `IContainer` and `INewDependency`. Now, work on this codebase for 5 years. You are going to have a lovely mix of `IContainer` and explicit dependencies. You are going to regret ever introducing `IContainer`.